# Настройка кастомного балуна в yandex map js api

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Недавно занялся интеграцией яндекс карт на свой сайт и решил создать свой макет для балунов. Разумеется я недооценил задачу :)

Сначала сверстал примерный шаблон для балуна, [вот он](https://codepen.io/Kirill58/pen/jOLYVgp).
Но вот гладко его перенести на карты у меня не получается. Делаю в песочнице на основе примеров. Решил пока не заморачиваться по поводу всяких "хвостиков", описал в коде базовый код (код из примеров), но даже это не получилось - балун просто зависает в левом верхнем углу, а крестик не закрывает балун. Плюс ещё в консоль выводится куча ошибок.
[image: отображение балуна на яндекс картах]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я неправильно сделал, как решать? Весь код ниже:

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init () {
    var map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [55.650625, 37.62708],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: []
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        counter = 0,

        // Создание макета содержимого балуна.
        // Макет создается с помощью фабрики макетов с помощью текстового шаблона.
        BalloonContentLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
            '<div class="balloon-root ">'+
                '<a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>'+
                '<div class="arrow balloon-pin"></div>'+
                '<div class="balloon-head balloon">$[properties.balloonHeader]</div>'+
                '<div class="balloon-body balloon">$[properties.balloonContent]</div>'+
                '<div class="balloon-footer balloon">$[properties.balloonFooter]</div>'+
            '</div>', {
            //Формирование макета
            build: function () {
                this.constructor.superclass.build.call(this);

                this._$element = $('.balloon-root', this.getParentElement());

                this.applyElementOffset();

                this._$element.find('.close')
                    .on('click', $.proxy(this.onCloseClick, this));
            },
            //удаление макета из DOM
            clear: function () {
                this._$element.find('.close')
                    .off('click');

                this.constructor.superclass.clear.call(this);
            },
            //закрытие балуна
            onCloseClick: function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                this.events.fire('userclose');
            },
        });

    var placemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.650625, 37.62708], {
            iconContent: "test",
            balloonHeader: 'Заголовок балуна',
            balloonContent: 'Контент балуна',
            balloonFooter: 'Футер балуна'
        }, {
            balloonShadow: true,
            balloonLayout: BalloonContentLayout,
            // Запретим замену обычного балуна на балун-панель.
            // Если не указывать эту опцию, на картах маленького размера откроется балун-панель.
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 1
        });

    map.geoObjects.add(placemark);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Настройка макета балуна метки</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--
        Укажите свой API-ключ. Тестовый ключ НЕ БУДЕТ работать на других сайтах.
        Получить ключ можно в Кабинете разработчика: https://developer.tech.yandex.ru/keys/
    -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU&amp;apikey=<ваш API-ключ>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="placemark_balloon_layout.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        html, body, #map {
            width: 100%; height: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
        }
        
        .balloon-root {
          width: 300px;
          height: 200px;
          position: relative;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: stretch; 
          border-radius: 10px;
          background-color: #808080;
          text-align: center;
          color: white;
          z-index: 10;
        }
        .close {
            position: absolute;
            right: 5px;
            top: 3;
        }
        
        .balloon{
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          justify-content: space-around;
          align-items: center;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        
        .balloon-head {
          border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
          width: 100%;
          height: 30%;
          background-color: #666;
          font-size: 20px;
        }
        
        .balloon-body {
          width: 100%;
          height: 50%;
        }
        .balloon-footer {
          width: 100%;
          height: 30%;
          font-size: 12px;
        }
        .balloon-pin {
          height: 30px;
          width: 30px;
          position: absolute;
          background-color: #808080;
          z-index: -1;
          bottom: -5px;
          transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не доделали макет, забыли добавить **applyElementOffset**

```
applyElementOffset: function () {
    this._$element.css({
        left:  - (this._$element[0].offsetWidth / 2),
        top:  - (this._$element[0].offsetHeight + this._$element.find('.arrow')[0].offsetHeight)
    });
},
```

С ним и балун появляется на своём месте верно и крестик его закрывает:
https://jsfiddle.net/h5cafurt/

Comment: Ого, спасибо, Вы прямо меня спасли!

Comment: прошу прощения, а можете объяснить почему на [сайте](http://test1.vesnikolsk.ru/organizations)  балуны не появляются? В консоли вижу ошибку:
`Uncaught Error: ymaps.modules: module "BalloonContentLayout@layout" is not defined.`
Хотя в коде можно увидеть что объявил шаблон.

Comment: Думаю, тут вопрос в типах данных и их формате, который вы получаете пост-запросом. Например "BalloonContentLayout" у вас получается не переменной, а строкой. Если удалить кавычки, ошибки уже нет. Хотя сами балуны всё равно нормально не отрисовываются ещё. Посмотрите на примере https://jsfiddle.net/zdvuj82p/ отдельной метке сохранил кавычки, а тем, что попали в кластер - нет. На ней в итоге выпадает ваша ошибка, на остальных точках - нет.

Comment: Понял, ещё раз благодарю за ответ :)